# What does this mean?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, post-ban

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of
>   being blocked from asking any more.
>   For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?
>   Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

Can I ask a question anyway?

Comment: It means what it says. Some of your questions were closed, downvoted, or deleted. This, as a whole, shows signs (at least on paper) that your contributions to the site might not be up to par with the basic standards of the community. It means that you need to fix what needs to be fixed, or the system will block you from posting new questions.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila  I ask only three questions!

Comment: Well, all three received downvotes, and one of them is closed.

Comment: @Achmed You're not exactly truthful. You have asked 10 questions. Seven have been deleted.

Comment: @arjafi When!? I can't remember

Comment: @arjafi that is not my fault
for example
what is wrong with this question!?
[Math needed to study Navier-Stokes existence and smoothness problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854575/math-needed-to-study-navier-stokes-existence-and-smoothness-problem)

Comment: @Achmed There should be links in that message (I believe to [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) and [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), but I could be wrong). Read the information contained therein and follow the advice given. I'll also add reading [this math.se-specific page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/). Edit your existing questions to improve them. Whether you get blocked or not largely up to you. (I'll add that these blocks are entirely automatic, and site moderators cannot override them.)

Comment: @Asaf Karagila 
How can a Question about one of the millennium problems To Be Considered As low-quality-posts!?

Comment: Here is an example, "Why should I even care about the Millennium problems?", is a terrible question for this website. Of course, this is a hyperbole and a half, but it goes to show you that the topic of the question is completely orthogonal to its quality as judged by the community here.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila what if their judgment is low quality?

Comment: If the judgement of the people on this website is of low quality, why do you want to spend any time here, Achmed?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson good point

Comment: See other questions that are well-received and use the same format. You will go nowhere by criticizing why my posts are downvoted or closed.

Comment: *How can a Question about one of the millennium problems To Be Considered As low-quality-posts!?*  The content/topic of a question is not the sole factor in determining the question's quality.  How the question is presented is also very important.  This is true in general.  More specific to this site, it's also important that the question follow the previously mentioned guidelines.

Comment: @Achmed The Stack Exchange tour (https://stackexchange.com/tour) clearly states that "This site is all about getting answers". As a result, to get a good question you MUST: 1) be relevant to the site, 2) have a good explanation and attempt of the question — to help others give the best explanation for you, and 3) respect other users and their opinions.

Comment: @Achmed In other words, the quality of a question depends on how much you have tried and thought about the question before posting — most people whether in real life or online won't help you unless you show some effort first. There is no such thing as a "free lunch".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can still ask questions, but you have to be careful.....if your next few questions are not well-received, you will be placed on a posting ban and you won't get to post questions for 6 months (as far as I know). If your next post after the 6 month ban isn't well received either, your ban will be reinstated. Trust me, I've had that warning over on StackOverflow. In order to avoid this warning, edit those badly-received questions you have (those with a score of 0 or less) to where they are higher-quality. Make sure that you have added any clarifications needed to your questions and use MathJax to format your equations if need be. Good questions will result in upvotes, which lead to good answers. So, just be careful on the quality of your next posts if you are ever under that warning.

Comment: I don't want to ask questions at this site anymore

Comment: This site will never accept any of my questions، According to probability theory

Comment: How can probability theory prove that Math.SE will not accept your questions? This sites accepts all questions. However, the most recognized are those with good quality.

Comment: Math.SE is not for everyone. There are many other sites you can use instead of this one, such as Quora. There is always the option to *leave*.

Comment: I never said the OP couldn't leave, though.